# Is it possible for 'bash -c' to use bashrc?

Tags: bash

I am currently switching to fish shell.

However, I am a bash one-liner lover and also for compatibility consideration. I think to use `bash -c 'bash one liner'` should be good.

However, some of my one-liner related to ~/.bashrc. Is it possible for `bash -c` to source ~/.bashrc before it runs command?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `BASH_ENV` environment variable should be used for this (`ENV` when `bash` is in POSIX mode), the expansion of the variable is used as the shell initialization file for non-interactive session. Note that, the value of this variable is subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion and the final filename is not searched in the `PATH`.

So just refer to the desired file as the variable value e.g. assuming `~/.bashrc`:

```
BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc bash -c '...'
```